# django jwt generate token if email confirmed

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-allauth

I have a situation guys, I'm using these packages in django for rest-api and authentication:

- `django-rest-framework` (REST API provider)
- `django-allauth` (User authentication)
- `django-rest-framework-jwt` (Support JSON-Web-Token)

In django-allauth, I made mandatory to confirm email after sign-up (`ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION = 'mandatory'`), login with session authentication is fine and follow this option, but jwt generates token and ignore this option.

How can I handle this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I found the answer.

We need to override `ObtainJSONWebToken` class:

```
def post(self, request):
     serializer = self.get_serializer(data=request.DATA)

     if serializer.is_valid():
         user = serializer.object.get('user') or request.user
         # check if settings swith is on / then check validity
         if settings.ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION == settings.ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION_MANDATORY:
             email_address = user.emailaddress_set.get(email=user.email)
             if not email_address.verified:
                  return Response(status=403, data='E-mail is not verified.')

         token = serializer.object.get('token')
         response_data = jwt_response_payload_handler(token, user, request)

         return Response(response_data)

     return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

**Note:** Remember, check email validity with setting switch `ACCOUNT_EMAIL_VERIFICATION`, because we need to keep this dynamic.